# Self-contained Python environment for Mac OS

Tags: python, macos

I need to make a fully self-contained Python environment for Mac, which can be transferred between different Macs running OSX and function independently of any other Python installations (or lack thereof).

In the enviroments I have created (using `venv`), I find that the /bin/python file and others are in fact aliases. When I replace these aliases with the original executables, the enviroment still does not work on other computers due references to files within a Python installation, such as

```
Library not loaded: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/Python
```

Is there a way to make the environment fully self-contained?

I would guess so, since tools such as `pyinstaller` and `cx_freeze` exist to make executables out of Python applications. So these must contain standalone environments somehow. But for my purposes, it is the enviroment that I need. Not an executable as these tools provide.

Comment: Do you mean for developing in Python or for deploying Python applications? [Anaconda](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/mac-os/) sounds pretty close to what you're describing (personally I prefer [miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html)).

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a virtual environment. Python comes with [`venv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) which allows you to create virtual environments. You could consider them self-contained, since all the necessary scripts for running Python are *in* the virtual environment. This goes with the package dependencies as well. You can have a variety of packages installed on your computer, but the virtual environment will have none of them installed (unless, of course, you install them yourself).

To create a virtual environment, run:

```
$ py -3.9 -m venv virtualenv
```

You can replace `3.9` with whichever Python version you are using and you can replace `virtualenv` with whatever you want to name your virtual environment.

To activate the virtual environment, you would run:

```
$ source virtualenv/Scripts/activate
```

And to deactivate it, you would run:

```
$ deactivate
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have used this (with the command `python3 -m venv virtualenv`) but the file 'virtualenv/bin/python' is an alias rather than the actual python executable. So these environments don't appear to be truly self-contained.

Comment: @quantum_jim Oh, so you want a Python script as an executable (.exe/.app)?

Comment: Perhaps that needs to be part of it, but I still need something that looks an acts like the kind of environment venv creates. Just one that can be and transferred between different macs and still work.

Comment: I have a similar need and in our case the best analogue is how applications will often ship the precise JRE they prefer to use, rather than referring to a system JRE. We'd like to do the same with Python, and it's difficult to figure out how.